# sqlite database protection for app upgrades

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios4

I have an app on app store with version 1.0. It use a sqlite database which users modify. I want to know if I issue an update to my app UI and release to app store. When users update their app will they lose their data? How to make sure they don't?

Comment: Research effort. Time to do some reading. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323

Answer (score 1):

Use the documents folder. If database is not there, copy from bundle, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`, to documents folder:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, do all interactions from the database in the documents folder. The documents folder isn't wiped during upgrades, only if you explicitly do so or if the user deletes the app in its entirity.